# How to use cross validation on linear regression model in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to use [grid search cross validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/grid_search_cross_validation.png) in scikit learn to train the Linear Regression model on lets say 10 folds just like in the image I shared.

But when I do that I get:

```
spipe = Pipeline([
    ('scale', StandardScaler()),
    ('model', LinearRegression())
])

grid = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=pipe,
    cv=4
)

grid.fit(X, Y)

TypeError: GridSearchCV.__init__() missing 1 required argument: 'param_grid'
```

So my understanding is it wants to iterate over possible parameters to the `LinearRegression` model and I should put those into `param_grid`.

But I don't want to tune a parameter for each fold. I want instead to simply do exactly what the photo shows: to do 10 folds and train and validate on them 10 times in order for the model to fine tune 1 linear regression polynomial (I suppose that's what's happening inside the model).

I tried using `cross_val_score` but it seems to train on the 10 folds 10 separate times because it returns 10 scores rather than 1 score (so I guess 10 linear regression polynomial, 1 for each fold).

So all in all, how do I use the folding cross-validation method with Linear Regression?

Here is the setup if anyone wants it:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

california = fetch_california_housing()

pd.set_option('display.precision', 4)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 9)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
california_df = pd.DataFrame(california.data,
                             columns=california.feature_names)
california_df['MedHouseValue'] = pd.Series(california.target)
X = california.data
Y = california.target
```

Comment: You are using the wrong class, you should use KFold

Comment: Nice!! thank you. Put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it, if you like. :) :) Thank you in any case!!

Comment: Hi @JeniaIvanov, did my more detailed explanation help you? If so, I would be pleased if you accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Snoopy already mentioned the issue in the commments. I want to provide you some deeper insights:

> I want to use grid search cross validation

We use grid search to find a model's and/or a pipeline's parameters (called *hyperparameters*) which generalize well for the given task and yield 'good' results across various datasets. Since there are no multiple datasets, we imitate multiple datasets by splitting it into folds.

The error you get is

> GridSearchCV.**init**() missing 1 required argument: 'param_grid'

The parameter grid, is the single/multidimensional grid of values which the hyperparameters can take during the grid search. `GridSearchCV` generates all possible combinations of the values in the parameter grid and tests their ability to generalize across multiple folds.

If you do not wish to search for a 'good' set of hyperparameters, but instead only want to cross-validate your pipeline/estimator, you can just use `KFold`, which is static and does not use and different hyperparameter combination. With KFold you are not comparing and tuning your current model's and piplines's parameters but instead build a different model for each fold with a static set of parameters.

> I tried using cross_val_score but it seems to train on the 10 folds 10 separate times because it returns 10 scores rather than 1 score

Yes, this is exactly what cross_val_score does: It builds one separate model for each fold, i.e. for each train/test slice of your whole dataset. You then can take the average and standard deviation of the scores to see how this parameter set would perform on 'different' datasets on average and how far these scores spread across multiple datasets, i.e. how well the model generalizes.